# Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive NullReference

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have an Activity which when the `onStart` method fires, it calls a web-service to get data. This Activity contains some buttons which allows the user to navigate to a different Fragment.

When data from the web-service is retrieved, it kick starts a `BroadcastIntent`.

If the user is within the Fragment in question, it catches the intent via a `BroadcastReceiver`. Within the `onReceieve` function, I am getting data which I have cached in to a `static` class **from** the web-service data.

So, this is the problem:

Within the `onReceieve` function, when I am trying to get the data from the static class, it is showing the data as null. Therefore when I try to access the inner objects of that data, it throws a NullReference.

The only time where it won't show a NullReference is if on the Activity screen, if I wait a good 10-15 seconds, let the data come back and populate the objects within the static class.

This approach is still the same as starting the fragment immediately. I have a callback function which fires when data is received from the web-service. And this function is ALWAYS called before the onReceieve. So WHY the data in the static class is showing null, I have no idea.....

Hope my description of the problem is coherent. If not, please let me know.

**Code**:

This code saves the data to the static class (And is always calls before the onReceive of the BroadcastReceiver).

```
for (int i = 0; i < myResult.getResource().getCategories().size(); i++) {
    ......
    MyModel.cachedResult.put(tempOfferType, category);
}
```

Immediately after this, I start the `BroadcastIntent`:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MyFragment.ACTION_REQUEST_RESULT);
this.getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

The `onReceive` function:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
    // Line below throws NRE because offers is null
                adapter = new OfferAdapter(getActivity(), 0, offers.toArray(new SinglePlusOfferVO[0]));

    ...
}
```

Again, if I wait 10-15 seconds on the main Activity then the NRE doesn't occur. If I immediately go in to the Fragment then the NRE occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. There was a problem with `Data` as oppose to how I had constructed everything.